# Does using an auto increment of 1 on numeric PK hurts performance?

Tags: performance, primary-key, auto-increment

A teacher of mine said that having an numeric PK with auto increment is a bad practice because it hurts performance.

He also said that Oracle database doesn't have an easy way to set up auto increment because of this.

He said that increment should be done on app instead of DB.

The performance penalty, if I remember correctly, would happen while inserting many rows, it had something to do with allocating a certain number of PKs IDs or something.

Is this true? If yes why?

Comment: Think of what could happen when you someone do an insert into the table with the auto increment key but not do a commit right away and other inserts start to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is that "it depends". In a lot of use cases, using an auto increment PK is good practice.

In InnoDB, the default storage engine in MySQL and MariaDB, the performance penalty of using the auto increment feature depends on the auto increment lock mode used. Two of the modes come at the cost of a table-level lock that is released once the statement has completed, which means only one statement can run at any one time. The third option (interleaved lock mode) doesn't lock the tables.

Oracle (12c) actually has auto incrementing keys ([identity columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1#identity-columns)). In previous versions you had to use sequences, which can serve the same purpose, and more. They are a bit more cumbersome to use, though, than auto incrementing keys.

The suggestion that applications should be generating these ID numbers on their own without the aid of the RDBMS' sequence or auto increment features really isn't realistic in a lot of use cases.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSmith I've edited the answer to include that piece of info

Answer (score 1):

> He said that increment should be done on app instead of DB.

That's **never** good advice as it **always** means a double-trip to the db. One to receive the last value, and another to insert. This also makes all kinds of bold assumptions about locking and concurrency.

> Is this true? If yes why?

**No**. It's not true. If you need the functionality, there is no better place for it than in the database. *Most* RDBM(s) use-cases *need* that functionality too, so it's just the price you pay, and it's not a major price. Test it yourself.

> Oracle database doesn't have an easy way to set up auto increment because of this.

Not true. It's pretty easy. Oracle has always had sequences. Now they have `IDENTITY COLUMNS`. You used to have to use a trigger that utilized the sequence. That's a bit weird and crufty, but it's still pretty easy -- and that's true to form with most things Oracle.

Comment: Oracle `IDENTITY COLUMN` uses a system created `SEQUENCE` behind the scenes.  The performance of the usage of a `SEQUENCE` via `IDENTITY COLUMN` is greatly improved when compared to using a `SEQUENCE` from within a `TRIGGER`.  `SEQUENCE` did not go away.  They got improved (session level `SEQUENCE` now exists.)

Comment: Ah, I see when I said *had sequence* I did not intend to imply that sequences went away. Past perfect vs past simple =( **fixed**